# Start page numbering at 0 with class book

Tags: titles, page-numbering

I try to begin my document with the `book` document class.

It work fine until I use `\maketitle`. So, a useless empty page (witch only contain the number “0”) is printed *before* the title page. But the title page still have the number 0…

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\date{\today}
\author{Foo}
\title{Bar Zee}

 \setcounter{page}{0}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \chapter{Preface} %want section number to be 0
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \chapter{Start From Here}
  \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

So, how can I set the 0 number on the title page (and not before), without having a useless empty page?

N.B.: This behaviour seems working only with the class book.

Answer (score 3):

The titlepage environment used by \maketitle does a \cleardoublepage and forces the title on an odd page. The 0 on the first page is simply from the header -- you could suppress it with \thispagestyle{empty}.

You can use the `notitlepage` option to avoid the extra page:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\date{\today}
\author{Foo}
\title{Bar Zee}

\setcounter{page}{0}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
  \chapter{Preface} %
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \chapter{Start From Here}
  \lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```